# Convert mpc playlist to table

Tags: bash, html, playlists, mpd

I have a block of playlist text from mpd state file with filename stateoyna as below.

```
song_begin: http://radio.virginradio.co.uk/stream
Name: Virgin_UK_128
mtime: 0
song_end
song_begin: http://46.20.3.200:80
Title: ARTEMIS GUNEBAKANLI - MANYETIK BANT     -
Name: RADYO EKSEN
mtime: 0
song_end
song_begin: http://stream.radyoodtu.com.tr:8006
Title: Bon Jovi - Livin' On A Prayer
Name: RADYO ODTU
mtime: 0
song_end
song_begin: http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio2_mf_p
Name: BBC Radio 2
mtime: 0
song_end
```

I want to convert this to an html table with song_begin, Title, Name are on the column headers. Is there any way to do that with a bash script using awk, sed etc.?